# Check the uniqueness of email. registration django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a registration on django. I can’t check the uniqueness of the email field during registration.

### ursl.py

```
path('accounts/register/', MyRegisterFormView.as_view(), name="register"),
```

---

### forms.py

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

---

### views.py

```
class MyRegisterFormView(FormView):
form_class = Register

success_url = "/accounts/login/"

template_name = "registration/register.html"


def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form):
    return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

---

How can this be realized?

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
     messages.error(request, "Эта почта уже зарегестрированна")
```

I understand that you need to compare the email with the filter and if it matches, return an error, but I can not implement this. How can I access the email form field in views?

Comment: Don't handle this in your form or your view. Handle it in your database: your `email` field should have a unique constraint on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

## In the model

If **every** user needs to have a unique email, it might be easier to add `unique=True` to the email field in your User model. This validation will be automatically applied to the form you're using.

## In the form

You can add field validation ([see Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/)) by adding a `clean_email` method to  your Register form like this:

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

  def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email', '')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      messages.error(request, "Эта почта уже зарегестрированна")

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```